# JPanel won't show up on Frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

The JPanel won't show on the JFrame and I have no idea why. It seems like the JPanel isn't being added to the JFrame somehow. Any suggestions?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LeaseItGUI extends JPanel{
    private int width=600,height=600;

    public void paintComponenet(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LeaseItMain extends JFrame{
    private int width=600,height=600;

    public LeaseItMain(){
        setSize(width,height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        LeaseItGUI theGui = new LeaseItGUI();
        setVisible(true);
        add(theGui);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        LeaseItMain LIM = new LeaseItMain();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the panel before `setVisible`

Comment: Further to the advice of @VinceEmigh. The panel should return a preferred size of 600x600. Add the panel to the frame. Set the frame not resisizable, **before** calling.. **Pack** the frame. Set it visible. It will be the exact size needed to display the 600x600 panel, and will itself be larger than that (different sizes depending on OS etc.).

Comment: I did, but to no avail none of the suggestions solved the problem... Something is weird with this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
add(theGui);
```

or

```
setContentPane(theGui);
```

before:

```
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I've done this as you can see in the main, I've tried your method but to no avail, this is a very weird situation as the panel simply won't show up on the JFrame

Comment: It does work- you mispelled paintComponent() as paintComponenet(), so nothings getting painted on the panel. That doesn't mean the panel isn't there.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how I live on a day to day basis... Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: What usually helps is to put `@Override` before a method that overrides a superclass/interface method. In this case, it would have given you a warning indicating that "paintComponenet" wasn't overriding anything.